# Algorithm for reducing edges in a sequence with out degree of 1?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm working with public transit data in the GTFS standard and have been building edge lists of origin stop to target stop in a sequence across an entire route. I've put some sample R code below to show a sample of the data and graph.

```
library(igraph)

# edgelist with two nodes with outdegree > 1. 
edgelist <- data.frame(source = c("Z","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F", "A"),
                       target = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
                       edge_sequence = c(0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA , NA),
                       source_node_out_degree = c(1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                       group = factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)))

# i would like to remove edges within my sequence that have an outdegree of 
# one and merge the original source with the 
plot(graph.data.frame(edgelist), edge.arrow.size = 0.3)
```

Below is the edgelist I would like to generate. In this example I've reduced the connection from A->F because it is a. along the sequence and b. only nodes with an out degree of one are between A and F.

```
# the expected edgelist after simplifying the network. Connecting nodes that 
# have outdegree > 1 on the sequence of edges. 
new_expected_edgelist <- data.frame(source = c("Z","A", "F", "F", "A"),
                                    target = c("A","F", "G", "H", "I"))

# edges with outdegree == 1 have been reduced. 
plot(graph.data.frame(new_expected_edgelist), edge.arrow.size = 0.3)
```

The application of this would allow me to simplify my network for visualizing only the edges that are shared between multiple public transit routes.  Some routes extend for many stops outside a connection to any other stop and make visualizing the complexity of network more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `contract.vertices` command:

```
g<-graph.data.frame(edgelist)
h<-contract.vertices(g,c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,8,9,10))
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's not part of my original question but do you have a good way to change the lists inside the new matrix into just a concatenation of the nodes it passes through?  I'm using ```as_edgelist(h)``` but the object is wonky.

Comment: The parameter `vertex.attr.comb` of `contract.vertices` might help, it says how the id of the new vertex arises from the id's of the old vertices. If you set it to `toString`, then the contracted vertex is called "B, C, D, E, F". See also [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/contract.vertices).